# Ruby: module A vs class A::B

Tags: ruby

So, I can have something like this (**A**):

```
module A
    class B
    end
end
```

and also I can have this (**B**):

```
class A::B
end
```

Why would I use **A** instead of **B** and vice versa?

Comment: The former is preferred because the latter raises an exception: `NameError: uninitialized constant A`. :-) If, however, you write `module A; end` before `class A::B`, I don't believe there is a difference. The former method, being more compact, and arguably clearer, is normally used. Of course, if you want to create modules and classes on the fly, all bets are off.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, why would I want to use `class A::B` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>When you are defining `A::B` for the first time, you have to take the first option. Otherwise,</strike> The second option saves indentation and is more compact, which is useful when you want to write something to `A::B` concisely and independent of other things in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in option **B** module A must be already defined. There are also some other issues with this option. You can read more about it here http://techblog.thescore.com/how-you-nest-modules-matters-in-ruby/